# How to increase height of JQGrid Pager

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I have a custom button in my navgrid that has a large title. Here is the problem

[image]

So how can i make the entire text appear properly ?

I tried to increase the height of the pager but t does not work

```
 <style type="text/css">

        .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager .ui-pg-div{

            height:auto;
        }

    </style>
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: It's important to know which version of jGrid or free jqGrid you use.